# How to reference .netstandard libraries in SSIS ScriptTask

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

Using Visual Studio 2015, I had an SSIS package that used an `ScriptTask`. The `ScriptTask` was using some portable class libraries following [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/) approach. but after a while I decide to change it to a *.netstandard* class library and everything was OK. I changed it to *.netstandard* and used it in other projects with no problem. But in SSIS packages that I'm using it, there is an error saying:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,...

So I add a reference to *.netstandard* dll and this error disappears but the package throws general runtime exception saying:

> DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code

Anyone has successfully reference a *.netstandard* class library in SSIS `ScriptTask`?

Comment: @Tarzan this is the same link as I provided in the question. I prefer not to sign the assembly in GAC and as I said in the question I'm looking for a solution following the approach introduced in that link. I expect if .netstandard is the recommended replacement for PCL, so it can be used anywhere PCL has been used without problem.